# Pycharm delete all unexpected argument

Tags: python, pycharm, compiler-warnings

I got a method or `__init__` with multiple argument, then I realize I do not need that argument so I delete it and rewrite the method. Now I have a lot of method/init call which have more argument than the method itself, resulting to unexpected argument.
[image]

I have a lot more unexpected argument than what the image shows, so much that I hope I do not need to delete the argument manually by hand. Is there any way to delete all unexpected argument automatically in PyCharm?

[image]

I do not want to silent the warning, I want to delete all the unexpected argument.

Simplified and exaggerated example of my problem

```
def foo(number):
    pass
    # code here ....

foo(1, "function call number 1")
foo(2, "function call number 2")
foo(3, "function call number 3")
.......
foo(1156, "function call number 1156")
```

Comment: Find where `foo` is getting called from & modify the call to remove the argument. Alternatively, leave the function signature as it is & just don't use the argument you don't need.

Comment: @rdas there is a lot of them , i'm looking for a way to do it automatically , otherwise it would take a very long time to remove every each of them

Comment: Try the `refactor` option in PyCharm. Right click on the method, Refactor -> Change Signature.